# How can I use a decorator inside a class with the definition in the same module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

Inside the `BasePlugin` module I have 2 main things defined. A class called `BasePlugin`, and a decorator that is not part of the class called `ValidateEvent`.

When I write a plugin and run:

`from BasePlugin import *`

This works and I can use the decorator on methods inside the plugin class.

However, if I try to decorate a method inside the `BasePlugin` class, it cannot find the decorator.

I have tried many ways to reference the decorator, and even tried to import it in to it's own module but nothing seems to work. I would rather not create another module for the decorator.

Is it possible to reference a decorator inside a class that is defined in the same module but not as part of the class?

Edit: Here is a snippet of the offending code

```
#BasePlugin.py
class BasePlugin():

   def __init__(self, event_manager):
      pass

   @ValidateEvent
   def ProvideModeEventHandler(self, event):
      self._mode = event.Message

def ValidateEvent(func):
   """
   Decorator used to check if the event(s) fired should be
   handled by the plugin.
   """
   def new_func(plugin, event, *args, **kwargs):
      if plugin.Name == event.Name or event.Name == '':
         return func(plugin, event, *args, **kwargs)
   return new_func
```

Comment: Yes it's possible, and if everything is as you've described, it should work. We can conclude that you made a mistake in the code that you didn't post, and we cannot solve your problem until you provide a [mcve].

Comment: This should be enough to show the problem. @ValidateEvent works from other files that use this module, but the class defined inside itself cannot find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is with the order of your definitions in the module. When you use `ValidateEvent` as a decorator on a method in the `BasePlugin` class, it needs to be available already in the global namespace, since the decorator runs immediately when the method is defined (not only when the method is called).

In the snippet of code you've shown, `ValidateEvent` is defined below the class definition, so the Python interpreter doesn't know about it yet.

To fix the issue, move your decorator's definition above the class definition:

```
def ValidateEvent(func):
    ...

class BasePlugin():

   @ValidateEvent
   def ProvideModeEventHandler(self, event):
       ...
```